# Change phone number in emulator - Android development

Tags: android, android-emulator

I need to set/change the phone number of the emulator for debugging purposes... Any help would be appreciated...

Thanks :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html....

cover this you will come to know to make changes in emulator

Comment: link is dead :(

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer has nothing to do with changing the default phone number. You need to recompile from source or patch the binary to change the first 7 digits. The last four of the phone number are the emulator's port number. Patching the phone number is detailed at the end of this blog post:

New link (images missing): http://blog.talosintel.com/2013/04/changing-imei-provider-model-and-phone.html

Web archive (slower, with images): https://web.archive.org/web/20150909014941/http://vrt-blog.snort.org/2013/04/changing-imei-provider-model-and-phone.html

Dead link: http://vrt-blog.snort.org/2013/04/changing-imei-provider-model-and-phone.html

Comment: Thanks, I updated the link to their migrated blog. It doesn't have images so the web archive link is very useful.

Comment: I was curious to find the spec that states how numbers should be encoded in little-endian (nibble swapped) bytes. I believe it is ETSI TS 124 080, 2.1b https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/124000_124099/124080/14.00.00_60/ts_124080v140000p.pdf

Answer (score -3):

hi 
 get phone no by calling getLine1Number() method from TelephonyManager class

```
TelephonyManager tmgr=(TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) ;
```

u can return static phone number

Comment: I can get the phone number using this code... What i want to know is, how to set or change the phone number, sim serial number, etc. There must be some configuration file or something like that... I am working in windows vista...