# How set the number phone for Emulator Android?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change phone number in emulator - Android development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867286/change-phone-number-in-emulator-android-development)

I'm running 2 emulator (A and B).

(A) has number default 5554 and (B) has default 5556 and I want to set (B) has number: 8701 or some thing like that and from (A) can send sms to (B).

Any idea for me?

Comment: AFAIK these are port numbers in the system and not virtual phone numbers and are limited to the range of 5554-5584.

Comment: @DavidKohen the port numbers do work as virtual phone numbers for emulator to emulator communication.

Comment: It mean I can not change emulator has number 8701. :( .Anyway thank for help, again!